# How to remove different listeners on the same object that are also listening to the same event?

Tags: node.js, listener

Does an **event** and a **listener** on a certain object act as an "identifying pair" for that listener?  Or just the **event** on the object?

reading over node.js documentation here:
http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener

For example, if you have two callback functions `listener_1` and `listener_2`:

```
var stdin = process.stdin;

stdin.on('data',listener_1);
stdin.on('data',listener_2);
```

then you remove the listener, with:

```
stdin.removeListener('data',listener_1);
```

**So, is `listener_2` still listening?**

Thank you.

ps. I tried test myself using `util.inspect` and `listeners` method but still not confident I understood how this works!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to remove all the listeners, you can use

```
stdin.removeAllListeners('data')
```

Otherwise, after calling

```
stdin.removeListener('data',listener_1);
```

listener_2 **is** still listening.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still thinking this through. So, to be clear, you always need to reference the listener by the exact name?? What if you have an anonymous listener, such as `stdin.on('data',function(data) { //do something});` How do you remove that?

Comment: You cant. If you plan to remove it, you have to name your function. But, it's not the name that is important, it's the reference. `var todelete = listener_1; stdin.removeListener('data',todelete);` works; because todelete is a reference to the Listener.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use an anonymous function but you need to save it somewhere.

```
var listener = function(){};
emitter.on('event', listener);
emitter.removeListener('event', listener);
```

But that means you can't use bind or the arrow function closure notation:

```
emitter.on('event', listener.bind(this));// bind creates a new function every time
emitter.removeListener('event', listener.bind(this));// so this doesn't work

emitter.on('event', ()=>{});// closure creates a new function every time
```

Which is annoying. This works though:

```
emitter.on('event', this.eventListener = () => {});
emitter.removeListener('event', this.eventListener);
```

So does this (storing listeners in a map):

```
emitter.on('event', this.listeners['event'] = this.myEventListener.bind(this));
emitter.removeListener('event', this.listeners['event']);
```

**This is not always an issue:**

- In the most common case there is only one listener.
- In the second most common case, there can be more than one but they all want removing together (e.g. because the emitter has finished its job).

Either way, you won't need to specify the function. However when you do, you do.